# Displaying iOS buttons with non-orthodox shapes

Tags: iphone, ios, button, uibutton

I have some icons that I would like to use for displaying buttons. The icons are not in separate files, I have one big photoshop image with each button being a layer.

When I export the layer corresponding to an icon, I get a PNG with the icon located at it's intended position and not centered in the image. Like this:

[image]

If I create an UIButton located at coordinates (0,0) then the button is positioned correctly, but It can be clicked anywhere in the view, and I want it to be clicked only where there is no transparency. I read how this could be solved, here:

[iPhone button with non-rectangle shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561585/iphone-button-with-non-rectangle-shape)

My question is if that solution will be accepted in the AppStore, and if there is a better way to do this? Will having several buttons that overlap create problems?

Comment: Crop your images before exporting. I'm not sure how exactly you do this in Photoshop. A rounded rect is close enough to a rect that you really don't need to mask off the transparent bits (and merely having large transparent bits of image is rather inefficient — turn on "Color blended layers" in the simulator/Core Animation instrument and look at the amount of red).

Comment: In Phtoshop: image -> trim -> trim transparent area

Comment: I wouldn't recomment having many fullscreen images that are transparent almost everywhere. Blending is expensive and the GPUs are fillrate-bound.

Comment: Thanks guys,one more question, how do I determine the first top left pixel from the PNG image(with the transparency) that is not transparent(i.e the actual icon that I want to display), in order to get the exact coordinates when creating the UIButton?

Comment: The correct way to create a single button with custom images would be to make the button the same size as your image.

Comment: Point your cursor at the right position and Photoshop's info pane should show you the coordinates. You might even want to take a screenshot, paste it into Photoshop, and set the layer blend mode to "Difference". Alternatively, ask your graphic designer to give you coordinates.