# Registering button clicks on image bounds only

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am making an iPhone application that uses hexagon images for button shapes. I add UIButtons to the View and then set the buttons images to be the hexagon image.

My buttons will be layed out like a beehive structure - as per the attached image. If all buttons are in a single row there is no issue.

But when you begin to add multiple rows of buttons, there will be an overlap of buttons - as can be seen by the blue highlighted areas on the attached image.
The dashed lines represent the underlying UIButton shape.

My question is how do I handle these overlapping areas?
For instance, if I add button 3 first to the view and then 1, 2, 4 & 5 in that order to the View, button 3 will only have a very small space for the user to click on to select it as the other buttons will overlap it and have "z-index" presedence (to use a CSS term).

Or the user can click on button 3, but they might click on the top left hand corner of it which will trigger button 1 clicked as an Action.

Alternatively, is there a way to create custom button shapes in Xcode? I can create a button in code but its either a square or a rectangle.

EDIT: I have seen [HERE](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561585/iphone-button-with-non-rectangle-shape) that allows you to only registers button clicks on button images where the Alpha != 0 but the issue is still that the Alpha for button 1 will overlap button 3 and therefore not register button 3 clicks in the overlapping areas?

[image]

Comment: You need to use custom shaped buttons to achieve this. refer this link http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html

Comment: Try this link https://github.com/piemonte/PBJHexagon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Link

https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton

It gives out a Lib for having buttons sense touch as per its assigned Images