# All buttons (Round, Triangle) have a rect frame as click area

Tags: swift, xcode, button, area

Why have all buttons a rect klick area?
I did 3 buttons

A: One as standard button from Xcode 
And rotate it 45* grad..

B: second  a picture (triangle) with a transparent background..

C: Third rounded button..

——————————————————

B: i take Image and did their function as button 
The prob is their have automatically a background rect as klick range

B1.2: I get their texture in sknode and take this texture as button..  failed

C: all round Button have a rect klick area too

A: I take a button and rotated it - failed

——————————————————

Watch the image 
Blue = the Button what I want, all buttons have a (red)
the background rect area thats u can kick

——————————————————

How I can do a button with only therm body ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is currently a bit hard to understand. You could try to improve its formatting to help others understand what your issue is, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: If I understand correctly, this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561585/iphone-button-with-non-rectangle-shape).