# How to trigger different actions on UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have created two UIButtons named with btnFirst and btnSecond. I wanted to triangle it accroding to screen,So i use bezire path to male UIButton triangly. I got success to make it. But when i click on any Button then both UIbutton action trigger.

Please help me to trigger two diffrent action on buttons

```
// Build a triangular path
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];
    [path moveToPoint:(CGPoint){0, 0}];
    [path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){0, screenHeight}];
    [path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){screenWidth, 0}];
    [path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){screenHeight, 0}];
    // Create a CAShapeLayer with this triangular path
    // Same size as the original imageView
    CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer new];
    mask.frame = btnFirst.bounds;
    mask.path = path.CGPath;
    // Mask the imageView's layer with this shape        
    btnFirst.layer.mask = mask;


    UIBezierPath *path1 = [UIBezierPath new];
    [path1 moveToPoint:(CGPoint){0, screenHeight}];
    [path1 addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){screenWidth, 0}];
    [path1 addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){screenWidth, screenHeight}];
    // Create a CAShapeLayer with this triangular path
    // Same size as the original imageView
    CAShapeLayer *mask1 = [CAShapeLayer new];
    mask1.frame = btnSecond.bounds;
    mask1.path = path1.CGPath;
    // Mask the imageView's layer with this shape
      btnSecond.layer.mask = mask1;
```

and action on buttons

```
- (IBAction)firstBtnClick:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"first");
}
- (IBAction)secondBtnClick:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"second");
}
```

First button is gray and second is green.
[image]

Comment: try clipToBounds = YES.

Comment: @christianmini not working..

Comment: @christianmini `clipToBounds` clips subviews to the bound of their parent not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that in the end all elements are some kind of rectangle. So in your case, you created two overlapping rectangles, which are displaying non overlapping triangles.

Luckily, you are not the first having this challenge: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1588727/1128713) is an answer to a similar question. Although it is for MacOS, it should give point you in the right direction.

**Edit:**
Since you are drawing the triangles with a Bezier path anyways, there is a much easier solution than checking for alpha as described in the link I have posted earlier.

You need to create your own UIButton class and overwrite the `hitTest(_:with:)` method.

> Returns the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy
>   (including itself) that contains a specified point.

The class could look like this:

```c
class PathButton: UIButton {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)

        // ensure mask is of type CAShapeLayer, otherwise you won't get access to the path property
        guard let mask = self.layer.mask as? CAShapeLayer else { return hitView }
        // ensure path is set
        guard let path = mask.path else { return hitView }
        // validate if the current touch was within the path
        return path.contains(point) ? hitView : nil
    }
}
```

The action of your custom button will only be triggered when the touch is within its path. If there is none defined, every touch triggers the button's action.

Comment: Let me know, if you need further help.

Comment: I am not getting, how to do this. You can assist me, or you have any example code

Comment: I have little time right now, but I can provide you some sample code later

Comment: @Yatendra sorry for answering that late. I was quite busy lately, but this gave me the time to come up with a much simpler solution to your question.

Comment: thanks for the answer., I will try to implement and let you know.