# Get point coordinate on an image

Tags: iphone, imageview

I have an imageview which displays a part of the human body. What I want to do is to assign names to specific regions on the image. I would like to put pis to certain places and whenever user taps on any of those pins display name and detail information about the touched part. Should I use an imageview or is there some other class to perform this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use UIImageView and attach a [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to that image, like UITapGestureRecognizer if you want to get interaction with a finger tap. You can get the coordinates using `-(CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use a UIResponder, and convert your image regions into separate images. In these images, use alpha = 0 to tile areas you dont want to be accepted as a click. Then in the code, bitmap the images and customly handle clicks. Then you can do a check to see if that click should be accepted.
This link explains in alot more detail.
[How to create a transparent window with non-rectangular buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527907/how-to-create-a-transparent-window-with-non-rectangular-buttons)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with the help of touches delegate.

Comment: Ok, I can get the touched coordinate with it's help, but how can I put a pin on the touched point and keep it there so that I see it whenever I load the view.