# How to add multiple imageView with different shapes?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uibezierpath

Currently I am working for a collage app. I want to draw collage frame and after that I need to add images from Camera roll or camera . I need the following type view
[image]

I have added 5 UIImageViews. To draw in shape I have added UIBezierPath  like for imageview1

```
UIBezierPath *path1 = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];

        [path1 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        [path1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(150, 0)];
        [path1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 150)];
        [path1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

 UIImageView *imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 0, 160, 300)];
imgView1 . tag = 2;
imgView1 . userInteractionEnabled = YES;
imgView1. backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
CGPathRef borderPathRef2 = [path1 CGPath];
CAShapeLayer *borderShapeLayer2 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
[borderShapeLayer2 setPath:borderPathRef2];
[[imgView1 layer] setMask:borderShapeLayer2];
imgView1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[borderShapeLayer2 release];

[view1 addSubview:imgView1];
```

Like this I have done for all 5. But after adding imageView5 touch is not detected on all other 4 views because its frame overlaping on the other four imageview.

So I am not getting how to design this . I need to add images to all imageviews by touch action.

Please help me. If someone have any idea about this then please share.

Thanks In Advance.

Following is the example 2 which is from **Insta Collage app**.
[image]

Comment: why dont you use button.You have background image as well as action?

Comment: If I will use buttons then only  imageview5 will do button action .

Comment: can you please share the exact image design you want to implement? this frame shows several alternatives to achieve the same. For being specific to your need, post a link

Comment: if you just need to get the user interaction back, after you add the other imageviews, add this `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageView5];`, then you will get it

Comment: It depends upon user. If user wants to add image first on imageview1 or may be imageview 5. This is the situation.

Comment: use UIButtons with type custom, and set image on click,,,the perfection will depend up on your designing team....

Comment: I will try to use UIButton. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @deepti see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527907/how-to-create-a-transparent-window-with-non-rectangular-buttons)

Comment: @deepti Have you solved this? I am facing the same issue can you please help??

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem by overriding hitTest:withEvent: method of UIView.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Getting View which is touched.
    UIView *testView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    //If this is self. and point hitted on Masked Layer(Which is hiding our UIView).
    if(testView == self && testView.layer.mask != nil && CGPathContainsPoint([(CAShapedLayer*)testView.layer.mask path], NULL, point, false))
    {
            //Then return nil. So Touch thinks that UIView has not clicked. and touch is passed to UIView which is behind this view. And again hitTest is performed on inner UIViews.
            testView = nil;
    }

    //Return nil. So touch thinks that UIView is not clicked.
    //Return self. So touch thinks self is clicked. and no more hitTest is performed.
    return testView;
}
```

Now i implemented a control called IQIrregularView for this problem.
Check this.

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQIrregularView

Answer (score 0):

You should try random shaped buttons

you can find your solution in this custom class found on [GitHub](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton)

It worked for me and hope will work for you also....

Happy Coding...........

Comment: There may be a chance to click on OBShapedButton. If you try my answer, It will work in all conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to detect a touch on a UIView within the path of a `UIBezierPath`, using Swift

My scenario is:

```
- UIView (Container)
  - UIImageView (masked with Triangle UIBezierPath)
  - UIImageView (masked with Triangle UIBezierPath)
```

In my container, I override `hitTest` and return the subview that was touched like so:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {        
    for subview in subviews.reversed() {

        // ** convert the touch to the subview space:
        let convertedPoint = subview.convert(point, from: self)

        // ** if the subview layer mask exists I know that it has a UIBezierPath:
        if let layerShape = subview.layer.mask as? CAShapeLayer {
            if let shapePath = layerShape.path, shapePath.contains(convertedPoint) {
                // ** return the subview with the path that contains the converted point
                return subview
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Hope that helps!