# Create Custom shaped button using CALayer

Tags: ios

what is the best way to achieve the following.
[image]

Basically what I want to do is to create an "intractable area" where the user can touch and subsequent actions will take place. For example in the picture the user taps the green area a pop is presented with some options. Similarly there would be different colour "intractable areas or buttons" with in that pizza slice, if you may.

I was thinking of having buttons created through CALayer and try to fit them with in the bounds of the empty state image, but i don't know how to achieve this. Any other ideas are well appreciated.
[image: Empty state of the pizza slice]

Answer (score 1):

I would subclass `UIButton` or `UIControl` to make your custom button. Then override `pointInside:withEvent:` to see if the touch event is within the correct region.

See these links for more info and ideas:

- [Non-Rectangular Buttons on iOS](https://lightyearsoftware.com/2012/01/non-rectangular-buttons-on-ios/)
- [Abusing UIView](http://jimkubicek.com/blog/2012/10/11/using-uiview/) (see section on pointInside:withEvent:)
- [How to create a transparent window with non-rectangular buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527907/how-to-create-a-transparent-window-with-non-rectangular-buttons)
- [iPhone button with non-rectangle shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561585/iphone-button-with-non-rectangle-shape)
- [OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton)

Comment: I ended up using OBShapedButton. Thanks for your input

Comment: @JunaidAhmed, you might want to add your own answer to your question explaining how you did it. I'm guessing other people would find this helpful, too.