# circular menu - create menu & call action only if area is clicked & not just icon

Tags: ios, menu

I want to create circular menu like below for iPhone app.

[image]

I searched many libraries or solutions, however was unable to find the same. What all have is when they click on icon, menu action is called, however I want to call action if I click anywhere on the button as shown below.

[image]

User action will only get called if I click anywhere in the user of user as shown in above image.

Any idea how to achieve this?

I have one idea as checking the x & y position of the tap and findout where its clicked (but this is very time costly)

OR

Is there any way to create buttons of these shapes?

Comment: @Moritz : for iOS...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a transparent window with non-rectangular buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527907/how-to-create-a-transparent-window-with-non-rectangular-buttons)

Comment: Checking the x & y position is not time costly, just a few calculations.  Find distance of click from center, if less than radius of inner circle then done.  Otherwise, use `atan2` to find `angleInRadians` then do something like `octant = 8 * angleInRadians / (2 * .pi)`.

Comment: `atan2` returns a value in the range -pi to pi, so this will work better `let octant = Int(4 * (angleInRadians / .pi + 1)) % 8`.  `octant` will then be in the range `0..7`.

Comment: @FahimParkar Can you please share with me how did you create this circular menu in iOS Swift? 
I am looking to create a somewhat similar menu and tried to search many libraries. but did not find a proper solution. Your help will save my time

Comment: @iCoder : Menu is nothing but whole image.. issue I had is which menu is clicked which was solved by below method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have one idea as checking the x & y position of the tap and findout
>   where its clicked (but this is very time costly)

That's actually a very good idea, and the calculations are not very costly at all.

```
// Function to compute button touched
//
// Returns:
// 0 - 7:  One of the 8 outer buttons touched
// 8:      Center button touched
// 9:      Touch outside of outer circle (no button touched)

func detectTouchedButton(_ touchPoint: CGPoint) -> Int {

    // Set these values for your situation:
    let innerRadius: CGFloat = 50
    let outerRadius: CGFloat = 150
    let center = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 200)

    // Compute horizontal and vertical distance of touch from center
    let dx = touchPoint.x - center.x
    let dy = center.y - touchPoint.y

    // was the center button touched?
    let distanceSquared = dx * dx + dy * dy
    if distanceSquared < innerRadius * innerRadius {
        return 8
    }

    // was touch outside of outer circle?
    if distanceSquared > outerRadius * outerRadius {
        return 9
    }

    // Use atan2 to get an angle between -.pi and
    // .pi.  Divide by .pi to get number in the range
    // of (-1...1).  Add 1 to get a range of (0...2).
    // Multiply by 4 to get a range of (0...8).  Mod
    // by 8 since 0 == 8 (same button)  
    return Int(4 * (atan2(dy, dx) / .pi + 1)) % 8
}
```

**Notes:**

- I flipped the `dy` calculation because the coordinate system is upside down.  This just returns the coordinate system to the `+y` is up mathematical sense and changes the final ordering of `0` through `7`.
- If you wanted, you could modify this to return an `Int?` and then return `nil` for touches that aren't on a button.