# How do I check multiple UIView subviews displayed on top of each other for a touch event inside a bezier path?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I've written some code that generates wedges of a wheel in UIViews, stores these UIViews in an array, and displays these UIViews on top of one another, inside of a container UIView. This basically draws a segmented wheel.

What I now want is for every UIView to receive touch events individually within it's defined bezier path, and return a unique identifier. This would in practice mean that every wedge of the wheel is an individual button.

The problem I have right now is that only the last UIView that was added to the array responds to a single touch event (I have it set up to print the touch location within the bezier path right now), after which the UIView added before that responds to a single touch event, until I've cycled through all the wedges/UIViews and none respond to touch events anymore.

Here's the class that draws the wedges; I've tried implementing some methods that should allow touch events to be transferred to other UIViews at the end of the code, but I can't get it to work.

```
import UIKit

class WedgeDraw: UIView {

var wedgeNumber:CGFloat = 4
var wedgeLocation: CGFloat = 2

var wedgeIdentifier = 0
var wedgePath = UIBezierPath()
var touchPosition = CGPoint()


override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let startAngle = (360 / wedgeNumber - 360) * (wedgeLocation - 1) * CGFloat.pi / 180
    let endangle = (360 / wedgeNumber - 360) * wedgeLocation * CGFloat.pi / 180


    let center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX, y: self.bounds.midY)

    let outerRadius = self.bounds.midX - 3
    let innerRadius = self.bounds.width / 8

    //defines end points of simulated Bezier archs as a CGpoint
    let endPointInner = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: innerRadius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endangle, clockwise: false).currentPoint
    let endPointOuterCounterclockwise = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: outerRadius, startAngle: endangle, endAngle: startAngle, clockwise: true).currentPoint

    //defines bezier arch curves
    let outerWedgeCurvePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: outerRadius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endangle, clockwise: true)
    let innerWedgeCurvePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: innerRadius, startAngle: endangle, endAngle: startAngle, clockwise: false)

    //draw line path

    wedgePath.append(outerWedgeCurvePath)
    wedgePath.addLine(to: endPointInner)
    wedgePath.append(innerWedgeCurvePath)
    wedgePath.addLine(to: endPointOuterCounterclockwise)

    //sets stroke and color properties and draws the bezierpath.

    UIColor.black.setStroke()
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    wedgePath.lineWidth = 3
    wedgePath.stroke()
    wedgePath.fill()


}

override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    if wedgePath.contains(touchPosition) {
        return nil
    } else {
        return view
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first {
        touchPosition = touch.location(in: self)

        if wedgePath.contains(touchPosition){
            print(touchPosition)
            print(isUserInteractionEnabled)
        } else {

        }
    }
}
}
```

Here's the Viewcontroller code that creates the array and draws the wheel:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var boardContainer: UIView!

@IBAction func checkButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

}

var wedgeViewConstructorArray = [WedgeDraw]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //creates array of UNIQUE wedgedraw objects
    for _ in 1...6 {
        wedgeViewConstructorArray.append(WedgeDraw())
    }
    drawBoard()
}

func drawBoard() {

    for i in 0..<wedgeViewConstructorArray.count {
        wedgeViewConstructorArray[i].wedgeIdentifier = i

        wedgeViewConstructorArray[i].frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: boardContainer.frame.width, height: boardContainer.frame.height)

        wedgeViewConstructorArray[i].wedgeNumber = CGFloat(wedgeViewConstructorArray.count)
        wedgeViewConstructorArray[i].wedgeLocation = CGFloat(i + wedgeViewConstructorArray.count + 1)
        wedgeViewConstructorArray[i].backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        boardContainer.addSubview(wedgeViewConstructorArray[i])
    }
}  
}
```

This is what the rendering of the wheel looks like, and the view hierarchy:

[Wheelimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYWXE.png)

I'm still very new to swift and coding in general, and I am pretty happy to get where I am, but I'm really stuck now, and have no real idea how to proceed. I hope I've managed to make it clear what my problem is!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related question with different approach for hit detection: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50697037/1630618

Answer (score 0):

Alright, took me a while to find an answer, but it's actually surprisingly easy.
This is what I got right now, and it works perfectly for what I need.

```
    // checks if point inside touch event is inside bezier path and passes on to next subview if false.
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
            let location = point
            if wedgePath.contains(location) == true {
                print("\(wedgeColor)")
                return true


    }
    return false

}
```